# A word which is closest to the meaning of 'relatable'

Tags: single-word-requests

A word which is closest to the meaning of 'relatable'.
For example, you watch a movie or read something and you have the strange sense of feeling that it has happened to you too, And you attach a deeper sense of meaning and understanding to it.

Comment: Do you refer to events "echoing with reminders" ?

Comment: Any good thesaurus will have [words similar in meaning to 'relatable'](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/relatable), such as engaging or accessible.

Answer (score 2):

How about "resonates" / "resonant" / "resonance" ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a synonymous adjective for "relatable" for the situation.

I **had a strong sense of déjà vu** when I saw the movie.

Hope it helps.

Comment: typo: *synonymous*, but wouldn't just "synonym" work better?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Adjective is used as a noun and synonymous is used as an adjective. I am not sure why just "synonym" would work better when there is an adjective for it.

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of: *I don't think there is a synonym for "relatable"...*

Answer (score 0):

You need to clarify which meaning of *relate*.

1. To be able to associate with?
2. To be able to give an account of?

I am concluding that you wish to refer to the 1st meaning - being able to associate yourself to an idea, concept or person.

A good word is "identify".

- "I can identify with you, with your situation, because I too had been betrayed by a boyfriend before", the young woman consoled her friend.
- She identifies herself with the Democratic caucus, even though she was elected as an independent.

Identity = being one with, being in a singularity, the token of your one-ness.

#### [i·den·ti·fy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/identify)  (ī-dĕn′tə-fī′)

v. i·den·ti·fied, i·den·ti·fy·ing, i·den·ti·fies

v.tr.

1. - a. To establish or recognize the identity of; ascertain as a certain person or thing: Can you identify what kind of plane that is? I identified the man at the next table as a famous actor.
   - b. Biology To determine the taxonomic classification of (an organism).
   - c. To ascertain as having a certain characteristic or feature: job candidates who are identified as overqualified; children who have been identified with hearing loss.
2. To consider as identical or united; equate: The Greek god Ares is identified with the Roman god Mars.
3. To associate or affiliate closely with: writers who are identified with modernism.

v.intr.

1. To consider oneself as sharing certain characteristics or attitudes as another: She identifies strongly with her grandmother.
2. To associate oneself with or admire something, such as a set of ideas: a language learner who identifies with a new culture.
3. To self-identify.

[Medieval Latin identificāre, to make to resemble : Late Latin identitās, identity; see identity + Latin -ficāre, -fy.]
i·den′ti·fi′a·ble adj.
i·den′ti·fi′a·bly adv.
i·den′ti·fi′er n.

*American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. Copyright © 2011 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. Published by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. All rights reserved.*